# Inbox Notifications Will Not Clear

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

About a week ago, some of my inbox notifications are refusing to flag as read, and therefore persist indefinitely.

[image: Stack Exchange Notifications Not Clearing]

I've tried multiple times clicking through each notification, and nothing I do seems to clear them out. Is there a newly introduced bug in this area?

Comment: Does the "Mark all as read" button work (rightmost link in the top bar of the notification dropdown)? That tends to work for me when nothing else does.

Comment: Indeed. I had only tried clicking all the messages one by one and didn't notice that. If you post as an answer, I can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nothing I do seems to mark my inbox notifications as read and clear them out.

As per the comment by [zcoop98](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/776523/zcoop98) click the text link "Mark all as read" at the top right of the notification popup.

This will mark all of your inbox items as read and clear the notification count.