# I'm clicking the same message multiple times to get it to clear, is it broken, or is something else happening?

Tags: bug, status-review, notifications, global-inbox

My inbox indicates that I have a message! I click it to see what that message is. My expectation is that the message would be cleared from the inbox's active queue (the red-circle number decrements and the inbox reference turns gray).

But it doesn't.

I've had to click my inbox entries in some cases *in excess of ten times* to get them to clear (and each time I click, the page must be reloaded to my browser). I apologize, but it's irritating. Is this a bug, or is it something like multiple comments piling up on a question, only the last one is shown in my inbox, and I have to click the inbox reference for each piled-on comment?

*Please note that this appears to be a bug as I've encountered only a single comment on an answer and had to click the notification many times to get it to clear. It's as if there's a massive delay posting to the database that's exceeding some timeout.*

- I am not trying to open the linked comment/answer/etc. in a new tab or window. I'm simply left-clicking the notification.
- I'm using Windows 10 and Firefox 117.0.1.

**Related questions**

This issue appears to be in now way new. The following posts appear to be previous complaints about this issue (both here and on other stacks).

- [Inbox notifications not consistently marked as read after clicking title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424147)
- [Inbox Notifications Will Not Clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388163/395595)

Please note that, as mentioned by Joachim, the accepted answer for the second question doesn't actually resolve the problem, it just circumvents it. When, after a few weeks away from SE, I find 20-30 items in my inbox, using "Mark all as read" does make it all go away, but I lose all of the functionality the enhancements were meant to have in the first place. So I agree with Joachim that, due to it being an accepted answer, it's not officially a duplicate.

Comment: Are you opening the link in a new tab? I've noticed it's somewhat weird but if I open in the current tab, it clears but if I open in a new tab, it stays unread.

Comment: @JBH what browser and OS? If iOS, then most likely same as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385959/tapping-on-the-message-from-inbox-doesn-t-mark-it-read-anymore).

Comment: There is also the still unsolved https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424147/inbox-notifications-not-consistently-marked-as-read-after-clicking-title It is really annoying that the notification stays unread more often than not. This ruins all the new features of the new inbox.

Comment: @Catija No, I'm not opening a new tab. This has been going on for at least two weeks.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Windows 10 using Firefox 117.0.1.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That Stack Overflow link is pretty much the problem I'm experiencing. Even the difference between title and inbox message body - though I thought I was just seeing things. I've worked for companies that don't solve obvious problems before moving on to the Next Big Enhancement, which appears to be happening here. It stinks.

Comment: I have this problem too sometimes. Clicking "Mark all as read" works

Comment: @Thinkr I agree that "Mark all as read" works... but it defeats the purpose of having the notification list as designed in the first place. Sometimes my job takes me away from using SE for weeks and I return to find 20-30 inbox queries. The red-dot number and highlighted links are incredibly useful for keeping track of where I am in the list when reviewing it.

Comment: @JBH Yes, I hope they'll fix it

Comment: I truly get your annoyance, but your edit didn't add anything useful to the post, so I reverted it.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388163/inbox-notifications-will-not-clear) could be the exact same issue, but an 'answer' circumventing the underlying problem was accepted, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: To get this on SE's radar, a [tag:status-review] tag needs be added to the question. A bounty draws attention from users, which is helpful when it needs more support or user input, but doesn't let the company know about the issue. Adding a [tag:status-review] tag generates a ticket in SE's task system, which will be triaged into a feature request/bug sent to developers. Without a [tag:status-review] tag, it should be assumed SE doesn't even know about the issue. To have a [tag:status-review] tag added to the question, raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag to request it be added.

Comment: Are you aware that you can click on the "mail" icon at the right side of each inbox entry to change that entry's status from read to unread or from unread to read without navigating to the page? Are you aware that you can click on the "Mark all as read" button at the top-right of the popup/dropdown to mark all entries as read? Are you aware that you can use the middle mouse button (or Ctrl-left mouse button) to open the entry in a new tab/window, which should mark the entry as read and cause the current tab to navigate?

Comment: Yes, all those are, effectively, workarounds. The problem *might* be a timing issue, given that you're navigating in the same tab/window with each click. It's possible that your browser starts navigating, which is the default action for the link, prior to the request that indicates the notification should be cleared reaching the point in the networking stack that it isn't canceled by the navigation prior to the POST actually being sent to the server. That *shouldn't* be the case, but is a potential cause. However, if that's the case, I'd consider that to be a bug in Firefox.

Comment: @Makyen Workarounds are useful, but don't solve the problem. I consider them a band-aid that simply gets SE off the hook. I don't have the authority to add the [tag:status-review] tag, so the info is interesting, but irrelevant. I'm doing what I can to highlight the problem. I've been a programmer for 30 years. This is not an issue with Firefox. It's far more likely an issue of a low-priority database update timeout or a queue-length limitation on the server side.

Comment: This problem is also in chrome.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate "[Inbox notifications not consistently marked as read after clicking title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424147/3773011)" on which I posted an answer with more details as to what's happening and some workarounds.

Comment: @Makyen Once again, `Workarounds are useful, but don't solve the problem. I consider them a band-aid that simply gets SE off the hook.` This bug is an irritation for every one of the millions of users of this service. It's reprehensible to believe any workaround is satisfactory. Back when I worked for an EDA startup, we bent over backwards to fix anything that affected *everybody,* and we had customers who rightfully slapped us hard for not fixing ubiquitous problems fast enough.

Comment: @JBH only SE can fix this. In the mean time, I'd rather not have to click multiple times and use a workaround.

Comment: @VLAZ Which is why I'm here, on [meta.se], inviting SE to get off their rear ends and fix it. Other posts have covered the workarounds. I want a fix.

Comment: [As have I in tried to do as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391909). But when the choice is between suffering while waiting or not, I'd rather not. Nobody is suggesting that a workaround means SE don't have to fix anything. But the reality is that you not using a workaround doesn't put any pressure on SE. Only ever makes you suffer for their non-action.

Comment: @JBH I understand your frustration about this and other things not being fixed by the company and share it. I wasn't trying to excuse the company from having to resolve the issue, but merely to make it easier to find associated discussions. I also wanted to let other users, and yourself, be able to find workarounds, as I care about the frustration they experience with this situation. Providing workarounds is the best I can do to alleviate the cause of their frustration.

Comment: @JBH Given that this question still doesn't have a [tag:status-review] tag, I feel I should remind you that questions like this one are ineffective at informing the company about the issue unless the question gets a [tag:status-review] tag. An "in need of moderator intervention" flag should be raised on this question requesting that an MSE moderator add a [tag:status-review] tag. [Note: For this specific bug, it's probably non-critical, because I did add a [tag:status-review] tag to the cross-site duplicate I linked above on MSO, where I am a moderator and can add the tag.]